# COUNT() Function Does Not Return Number Of Rows

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm working on a blogging system website. In this blogging system, I have two tables. One is called `blogs` which simply contains the information of a blog (such as *blog_title*, *blog_author*, *blog_category*).

And the other one is called `categories` which only contains the *blog_category* names of blog posts.

Now I have made a page where users can see the blog categories and **the number of blog posts within that custom category name**.

So here is how it looks like:

[image: print screen]

And this is the code behind of that:

```
foreach($catShow as $cat){ 
echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$cat['table_id']."</td>
        <td>".$cat['cat_title']."</td>
        <td>".$cat['cat_id']."</td>
        <td>".num_cats($cat['cat_id'])."</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

So the function `num_cats()` basically counts the number of blog posts at `blogs` table which has the same blog category id (`cat_id`):

```
function num_cats($id){
        $num_cats = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blogs WHERE blog_category = '$id'";
        $run_num = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con2'],$num_cats);
        $return = '';
        if (!$run_num) {
            die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con2']));
        }
        $numCat = mysqli_num_rows($run_num);
        $return .= " 
            $numCat
        ";
        return $return;
}
```

But now the problem is, the result is incorrect. I mean the table only shows **1** result for each category however some of them have more than one item at the `blogs` table.

So what is wrong with this code, can you please help me with that!

Comment: Use join query with group by tag for blog category id

Comment: @Sachin Please explain more about, I haven't used it before.

Comment: Can you share your bolg category and blog post table structure?

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blogs WHERE blog_category = '$id'" will return one row. So $numCat becomes 1. You need to fetch your query result and get the value of COUNT(*)

Comment: **Caution**: This is open to SQL injection, use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"SELECT COUNT() FROM blogs WHERE blog_category = '$id'"
```

will return one row. So $numCat becomes 1.

You need to fetch your query result and get the value from COUNT()

```
function num_cats($id){
    $num_cats = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM blogs WHERE blog_category = '$id'";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con2'], $num_cats)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['count'];
    } else {
        die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con2']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` will give number of `blog_category` in your database. so in the result have only one recode with category count.

but you calling `mysqli_num_rows` this again. so, result will be 1 always.

just remove `mysqli_num_rows($run_num);` and update query with result col name,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM blogs WHERE blog_category = '$id'
```

then call

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($run_num);
$numCat = $row->total;
```

Comment: You will need to **fetch** the result somehow before using `$numCat = $run_num->total;` It might be useful to add that to your answer

Comment: of course @RiggsFolly thank you for remembering that

Answer (score 0):

Use join for better performance

```
$sql = "Select table_id,cat_title,bc.cat_id,count(b.category_id) as total_post from blog b inner join blog_category bc on b.blog_category_id=bc.blog_category_id group by b.category_id";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con2'],$sql);
while($cat = $result->mysqli_fetch_row()){
echo "
   <tr>
    <td>".$cat['table_id']."</td>
    <td>".$cat['cat_title']."</td>
    <td>".$cat['cat_id']."</td>
    <td>".$cat['total_post']."</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>";
}
```